# How do you move an Azure Devops Server project to a different collection?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-server-2019

In Azure DevOps 2019 Server. How do you move an existing project in an existing collection to a different existing collection on the same server instance?

Answer (score 0):

You don't. There is no mechanism to move projects across collection boundaries. A full fidelity migration of data is simply not possible.

It has been a common feature request for many years, but there are apparently significant technical hurdles that would have to be addressed in order to accomplish it; the product was just never designed for projects to be portable across collection boundaries.

Comment: Nothing native from MS agreed.  You can try and use Martin's migration tool, but it's not super simple. check out here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration.  Good luck.